# How to automatically restart Scrapy when the scraping is completed

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to automatically restart my spider when the  scraping is completed, more particularly when the response status is bad.
For example, I've got this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from datetime import datetime
import re

class level1(BaseSpider):
    # Crawling Start
    CrawlSpider.started_on = datetime.now()

    name = "level1"
    base_domain = 'http://www.google.com'

    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3

    restart=False

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 302, 503, 999, 200] #add any other code you need

    # Call sendEmail class
    email = sendEmail()


    # Call log settings
    saveLog = runlog()


    # Init
    def __init__(self, url='', child='', parent=''):
        self.start_urls = [url]
        self.child = child
        self.parent = parent

        #run baby, run :)
        super(level1, self).__init__(self.start_urls)


        # On Spider Closed
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, reason):
        if self.restart:
            print "we need to retry"
            super(level1, self).__init__(self.start_urls)
        else:
            print "ok"
            # parsing time
            work_time = datetime.now() - CrawlSpider.started_on

            # Correct Finished
            if reason == "finished":
                print "finished"

    def parse(self, response):

        if response.status == 503:
            self.restart = True
        if response.status == 999:
            self.restart = True


        if str(response.status) == "200":
            # Selector
            sel = Selector(response)
            todo
```

In the spider_closed method, I try to restart my spider when the response status is bad, but it's not work.

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if calling **init** is going to restart your spider.

Take a look at this link: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/api.html?highlight=scrapy%20start#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.start

In worst case you could write a separate program that spawns crawler using this core API (from link) and restart as necessary. Though i agree restart inside spider script would be much simpler.